# printing FILES then DIRECTORIES, no dirent.h

Tags: c, if-statement, cmd

I am having trouble with some ordering. My code segment works properly however, I am having trouble listing all files and THEN all directories. I have been stuck on this for a few days experiencing with different ideas and have not got too far. Thank you guys!

```
do
{
    // DIR serach
    if (ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        _tprintf(_T("%s  <DIR>\n"), ffd.cFileName);

    //else file search
    else
    {
        fileSize.LowPart = ffd.nFileSizeLow;
        fileSize.HighPart = ffd.nFileSizeHigh;
        _tprintf(_T("%s   %ld\n"), ffd.cFileName, fileSize.QuadPart);
    }

    // continue the search until no files
} while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);
```

Comment: a recursive function to walk the directory tree is your answer.

Comment: I mean I know I have to use recursion, however I have to get it to work for one case first. and this does not work for even one case. It just list them in random order.

Comment: Any suggestion of how to fix it for one case? so I can move to the next step which is recursion

Comment: Don't try to print the dir or file name in the current loop you used to walk the tree.  Save the names and type into different array(s) and print them in separate loop.